# AWS Cognito iOS. Unauthenticated error after logout

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-ios, amazon-cognito

I'm using AWS Cognito, integrated with iOS app through MobileHub to login via Facebook.
Everything works fine until I logout of existing identity and try to login with another FB account (or even with the same).
In this case I get this error, every time I call any AWS Lambda:

**AWSiOSSDK v2.4.9 [Error] AWSCredentialsProvider.m line:577.

[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider credentials].

Unable to refresh. Error is [Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={__type=NotAuthorizedException, message=Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool.}]**

But if I terminate and restart the app, everything works correct again.

This error originates [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/b79dbbc9b1547684092028792c0a17448265705a/AWSCore/Authentication/AWSIdentityProvider.m#L309):

From reading AWS SDK code I see, that it happens because cognito identity doesn't get logins from credential provider [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/b79dbbc9b1547684092028792c0a17448265705a/AWSCore/Authentication/AWSIdentityProvider.m#L301):

I guess this is expected, since I've logged out. But the problem is that even after logging in to FB AWS still considers me Unauthorized. From similar questions on StackOverflow I see, that in past people set logins dictionary on AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider manually. But now this property is deprecated and other similar properties are readonly.

Here is my AWS setup in AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

```
let cred = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .euWest1, identityPoolId: "POOLID")
let config = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .euWest1, credentialsProvider: cred)
AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = config

if let config = config {
       config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30
       config.timeoutIntervalForResource = 30
       config.maxRetryCount = 3
       AWSLambdaInvoker.register(with: config, forKey: "key")
}

let mapperConfiguration = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapperConfiguration()
mapperConfiguration.saveBehavior = .updateSkipNullAttributes
AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.register(with: config!, objectMapperConfiguration: mapperConfiguration, forKey: "updateObjectMapper")
```

And here is logout code:

```
AWSIdentityManager.defaultIdentityManager().logout { (result, error) in
   if let cp = AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration.credentialsProvider as? AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider {
           cp.clearKeychain()
   }
       // Open login screen
}
```

Please note, that I tried both clearing keychain and not doing it. The result is the same.

I'd really appreciate any help!
Best regards, 
Alex

Comment: I use the same AWSIdentityManager doing logout and have some problem like you. It shows 
```UserInfo={__type=NotAuthorizedException, message=Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool.}```
But still logout successfully I don't know why.
Any solutions?

Comment: What service gives you this error? Some AWSLambda? Or AWSIdentityManager itself?

Comment: AWSIdentityManager. And it deal with custom login like a charm, But when I logout using `[[AWSIdentityManager defaultIdentityManager] logoutWithCompletionHandler:^(id result, NSError *error)`
It appear the error I mentioned above. I need to do another job after detect logout has no error. Now I use `[[AWSIdentityManager defaultIdentityManager] isLoggedin]` instead to do another job when I detect user is logout in the handler above.

Comment: Same. Did you figure it out?  I just ignore any errors returned now.

Comment: @BillBunting I've ended up forking aws-sdk-ios and modifying AWSAuthCore to fix these issues myself. I don't remember what exactly I've done, but you can inspect my commits here https://github.com/Alex-Ozun/aws-sdk-ios/commits/reactoo

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this in the implementation of the logins method?

```
- (AWSTask<NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *> *)logins {
    FBSDKAccessToken* fbToken = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken];
    if(fbToken){
        NSString *token = fbToken.tokenString;
        return [AWSTask taskWithResult: @{ AWSIdentityProviderFacebook : token }];
    }else{
            return [AWSTask taskWithError:[NSError errorWithDomain:@"Facebook Login"
                                                          code:-1
                                                      userInfo:@{@"error":@"No current Facebook access token"}]];
    }
}
```

[More details](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/facebook.html).

Comment: Hi, Rachit! I'm not using custom AWSIdentityProviderManager to instanciate AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider, as you may see from my code. Therefore I don't have own implementation of "logins" method. Instead I use [enhanced](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication-flow.html) flow, which relies on AWS SDK to handle logins. Here is example of my login `AWSIdentityManager.defaultIdentityManager().loginWithSign(AWSFacebookSignInProvider.sharedInstance()) { (result, error) in {}`